# Why does this process not give me all solutions to $y'=ty^{\frac{1}{2}},\;\;\; y(0)=0$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation

> $$y'=ty^{\frac{1}{2}},\;\;\; y(0)=0 \tag{1}\label{1}$$

My question is: why does the following process not give me all the solutions for ($\ref{1}$)?

---

**My process**
$$(1)\implies y'y^{-\frac{1}{2}}=t\iff \int y^{-\frac{1}{2}}y'dt=\int tdt \tag{2}\label{2}$$
let $u=y$ then $du=y'dt$ so
$$(\ref{2}) \implies \int u^{-\frac{1}{2}}du=\frac{t^2}{2}+c$$
$$\implies 2\sqrt{y}=\frac{t^2}{2}+c$$
$$\implies y=\left(\left(\frac{t}{2}\right)^2+c\right)^2$$
but $y(0)=0$ so $c=0$. So we end with the solution
$$y=\left(\frac{t^2}{4}\right)^2.$$

---

My problem is that, if we let $a>0$ the functions

$$y(t) = 
     \begin{cases}
       0 & |t|<a\\
       \left(\frac{t^2-a^2}{4}\right)^2 &|t|\geq a \\
     \end{cases}$$
all satisfy equation ($\ref{1}$) yet none of them came from my process.

Why is it that my process doesn't give me all the solutions? Is there a way to know if I have found all the solutions to an equation? Is there a systematic way of finding them?

Comment: Already in the first step where you write $y^{-1/2}$, you need to assume that $y \neq 0$, so you might suspect that there could be a problem when $y=0$.

Answer (score 3):

$y(t)=0$ is obviously a solution.

The $y$-derivative does not exist at $y=0$, there is no local Lipschitz condition, so no enforced uniqueness from the Picard-Lindelöf theorem.

The solution that you found shows that the zero solution can be connected to non-zero values in finite time along solution branches. Everything starting between two of these branches must run into one of these solution when moving in direction of the branching point, so you get an infinity of branches.

Between uniqueness via Lipschitz and obvious branching there exist intermediary situations that have to be treated individually. The main points to explore is if the singular curve is a solution at all, and if it can be reached in finite time from points not on it.